# How to pass data (selected item) to Durandal composed detail view?

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, parent-child, single-page-application, durandal

I've started using (as of, a few hours ago) [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com) with the hope to manage views and allow composition within a single page - the previous approach, also using Knockout, was getting too unwieldy to maintain in a fat HTML file.

I've installed/setup Durandal and I can create views and viewmodels - however, I don't know how to get data *into* the viewmodel to use as a *basis* for the new viewmodel.

For instance, I have a "left nav bar" for selecting items - when an item is selected it updates a "selected item" observable in the current model, but it should *also* load the correct "detail view" in the right: because part of the reason to try Durandal to separate the components/views, this should come from a separate view/viewmodel.

I've read through the documentation including [Composition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition.html) and [Using Composition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html), but the method as to *how* to pass data to the viewmodel is not clear to me. It seems like I could use a view with an existing model (in the current view/scope), but I'd really like to merely use some of the current model data (i.e. an id) to fetch the "real" model data in the view.

Thus, my questions;

- How is passing initial data, such as the "selected item" to a viewmodel handled? I would prefer to use the declarative "compose:" binding, as that is what make KO .. KO.
- Is this notion of having/passing initial data the correct way here, or is there a better alternative? I have seen "activeItem" vaguely mentioned, but the details/useage aludes me.

---

Update 1: I've found [How do we share the data between views/Pass the data view to view](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/kGZSqT-4GBU), but the responses are lacking in actual implementation. I'd really like to not share the viewmodel between parent-child (distinct view/viewmodel pairs) and I'd like to use a declarative approach (no events). The parent need not know about the child, but the child needs to be fed data from the parent.

---

Update 2: While above I hinted only the "id" was required, I would like an approach that works with *any* basis object, which the router is not necessarily suitable for. Deep linking is not a concern in this case. However, if you feel the router is *the way* to approach this, post an argument for such (with details) as an answer and I'll at least give it an up-vote ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the breeze source code, you can see an example of a master-detail approach.

They are using an activator to compose the child view.

https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/TempHire/TempHire/App/viewmodels/resourcemgt.js

I don't know if you are using breeze or not, but the approach is independent of how do you get the data.

Comment: I ended up using this approach, and it works, but it would be really nice if `compose:` could pass `activationData`, similar to `modalDialog.show(id, activationData)` (without hacking the core) ..

Comment: An `activationData` feature was added to composition recently. It is passed to the viewModel's `activate` method, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great writeup on how to do this with John Papa's SPA template for Visual Studio by Eric Panorel here: http://ericpanorel.net/blog/hot-towel-spa-master-detail-scenario.

In short, you can take advantage of routing in Durandal, and it would go something like this:

`master.js` will expose a set of items:

```js
define(function() {
  var self = this;

  this.items = ko.observableArray([]);

  var activate = function() {
     // ... get your items
     self.items([ { id: 0, name: 'Item 1' }, { id: 1, name: 'Item 2' }]);
  }

  return {
    // some properties and ...
    activate: activate
  }
});
```

`master.html` will bind them and link to details view:

```
<section data-bind="foreach: items">
   <a data-bind="text: name, attr: { href: '#/item/' + id() }"></a>
</section>
```

Now, all that remains it to use route data parameter to pull the ID out in the detail viewmodel, `detail.js`:

```js
define(function() {
  var self = this;

  this.name = ko.observable();

  var activate = function(routeData) {
     var itemId = routeData.id;

     // ... get your item details
     // var details = ...

     self.name(details.name);
  }

  return {
    // some properties and ...
    activate: activate
  }
});
```

Finally, you will need to specify the route in your `main.js`:

```js
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router'],
function(app, viewLocator, system, router) {

    //>>excludeStart("build", true);
    system.debug(true);
    //>>excludeEnd("build");

    app.title = 'Durandal app';
    app.start().then(function() {
        toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
        toastr.options.backgroundpositionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';

        //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
        //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        //configure routing
        router.useConvention();
        router.mapRoute('item/:id', 'viewmodels/item', 'Item', false);

        app.adaptToDevice();

        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application with a transition.
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
    });
});
```

And there you go!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's possible to pass any basis object as we do with modal call. `ko.compose` is passive; with durandal router, you can carry your data to where you like. Have a look to my [work-around in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472791/2198331) and help to perform.