# Durandal Composed multiple view for registration page

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, single-page-application, durandal

I building an SPA with Durandal. I am doing a registration page now. This page is composed of 4 steps, step 1 to step 4.

I have a register.html and register.js which is composed by the shell when user click the register button in the Nav bar. This page has the steps navigation, and a next button. The center of this page has the steps views, regstep1.html and regstep1.js and similarly for all other steps.

As click next button, I would navigate to the next step using Compose. As sample below when moving to step2 from step 1.

```
<div data-bind="compose : 'viewmodels/account/regstep2'"></div>
```

Before moving to next step, need to validate the inputs. Once in the final step, i.e step 4, I need to call the function to register the user. The data passed to this function is as following:

Step1 - get the Name from the text box.
Step2 - get the Company name from the text box.
Step3 - get the phone number from the text box.
Step4 - Finish and register the user.

As you can see, I have to get data from each step and finally send this data to the registration function?

Currently, all the compose, steps navigation, validation works fine. Even registration works fine if I get all data in one step and call register function directly in that step. But I need to seperate the steps as I have multiple data capturing in all the steps.

please help? Is the a global variable or something like that, where i can store the data temporarily in each step and finally get the final data?

What is the best approach in this kind of scenario? Is my approach is correct?

PS: The actual steps data need to be captured in each step is more that shown above. I try a simple thing first before going to add all the requirements.

Comment: I have read [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327653/how-to-pass-data-selected-item-to-durandal-composed-detail-view?rq=1) that says i can pass the data to the activation function. If i use this can I pass the data from one step to the other as I move through the steps? But what if I move backward?

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk architecture.  What you have here is a *web flow*.  Ideally, what you want is to route to something we might call a `WebFlowMediator`.  You would probably call it `RegistrationMediator` in your case.  I'm going to stick to generic terms for the sake of simplicity.

You would then create views to be mediated by the `WebFlowMediator`:

- registrationStep1.html, registrationStep1.js
- registrationStep2.html, registrationStep2.js
- registrationStep3.html, registrationStep2.js

Your mediator is essentially a finite state machine (FSM), moving between the state of being in step 1, the state of being in step2, etc., and perhaps other states.

We use this exact approach with our Datepicker.  take a look at this [video](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=16C2A8798026D00B!173&authkey=!AIf5f0R_TXMvV0M&ithint=video%2Cmp4), and then look at the code below.  Don't be intimidated by the code below.  Pay particular attention to the line that starts with `this.stateMachine = new machina.Fsm({`, and then, within the state machine, look at the `states` property.

The Datepicker is doing exactly what you're doing: collecting up values from different steps.  With a Datepicker, we're collecting a day/month/year from the first view, but then the user may wish to change just the month, or just the year.  The mediator is responsible for assembling the information into a human-readable date, and then passing it out to the client.

We use **PostalJS**, **MachinaJS**, and the PostalJS plugin for MachinaJS.  The latter is really powerful: it converts messages on the bus to internal state machine events.  The gentleman who maintains these projects, Jim Cowart, is on the Telerik team.

NOTE: The individual views managed by the mediator are not child routes.  They are compositions that are dynamically revealed or hidden based on the value in the `currentView` observable.  We composited the views this way so that all of them would be loaded into memory at once to improve performance.  You could just as easily do this:

```
<div data-bind="compose: {
    model: currentViewModel(), 
    view: currentView(), 
    activate: true, 
    activationData: activateWith }"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that the model and view themselves are observables.

**THE BENEFIT**

The benefit this approach is extensibility.  You can add views without much effort, and you can even at states that allow for backpedaling, invalid responses, the notion of save for later, etc.

**CODE**

**datepickerMediator.js**

```
/** 
 * The `DatepickerMediator` sits in between the `DatepickerWidget` and each of the `DatepickerWidget`'s views, telling the views how to activate, listening to requests
 * from the views that might be of interest to the `DatepickerWidget`, and handling the `DatepickerWidget`'s change of state.  *State* in this case refers the current
 * view, the animation associated with transitioning to that view, and what the user has selected so far from each view visited by the user.
 * 
 * As its name suggests, the `DatepickerMediator` uses the Mediator Pattern (GoF).  In that sense, it holds a reference to both the `DatepickerWidget` and each of the
 * views (Month, Months, and Years). The reference, however, is merely a message bus channel.  There is no hard reference.  Consequently, we have high cohesion and loose
 * coupling.
 * 
 * An **internal message bus channel** creates a closed bus between the `DatepickerMediator` and each of its views.  An **outlet message channel** creates a closed bus between
 * the `DatepickerMediator` and the `DatepickerWidget`.  The views cannot access the `DatepickerWidget`'s outlet message channel directly.  Any message that must be
 * passed up to the `DatepickerWidget` from the views must be relayed, first, by the `DatepickerMediator`.  That is why, for example, the `DatepickerMediator` both subscribes
 * *and* publishes a `popover_resize` message.
 * 
 * {@img datepicker-relationship-diagram.png}
 * 
 * @class widgets.common.datetime.DatepickerMediator
 * @requires constants
 * @requires knockout 
 * @requires moment 
 * @requires postal
 * @requires messageTopics
 * @requires underscore 
 * @requires utils
 * @requires machina
 * @requires machina.postal
 */
define(
[
    'appservices/constants',
    'knockout',
    'moment',
    'postal',
    'messageTopics',
    'underscore',
    'utils',
    'machina',
    'machina.postal'
],
function (
    k,
    ko,
    moment,
    postal,
    messagetopics,
    _,
    utils,
    machina
    ) {

    /**
     * @method constructor
     * Creates a new `DatepickerMediator`.
     */
    var DatepickerMediator = function () {
        var _self = this;

        /**
         * @property {Array} subscriptions
         * Holds all of the subscriptions subscribed by the `DatepickerMediator`.
         */
        this.subscriptions = [];

        //TODO: Consider renaming to outlet
        /**
         * @property {Object} content
         * Outlet to `DatepickerWidget`.
         */
        this.content = {
            outletMessageChannel: '',
            queryable: null
        };
        /**
         * @property {String} currentView
         * String representation of view currently displaying in the `DatepickerWidget`.
         * @observable
         */
        this.currentView = ko.observable('');
        //TODO: Consider renaming to activationParams
        /**
         * @property {Object} activateWith
         * Pass-through activation parameters to the current view composition.
         */
        this.activateWith = {
            internalMessageChannel: utils.uniquify('widget/datepicker/'),
            keyboardContext: ''
        };
        /**
         * @property {machina.Fsm} stateMachine
         * Finite state machine (FSM) that drives the changing of the `DatpickerWidget` views.
         * 
         * The state machine has internal methods that are used to manipulate its state internally, and safely from outside the machine:
         * 
         * + getSelectedDateRaw
         * + getSelectedDateAsMoment
         * + getSelectedDate
         * + setSelectedDate
         * + setSelectedMonth
         * + setSelectedYear
         * + setSelectedDay
         * + publishViewReady
         */
        this.stateMachine = new machina.Fsm({
            initialState: k.uninitialized,

            //Here, machina allows us to hook into the message bus
            namespace: _self.activateWith.internalMessageChannel,

            //An object that holds the constituent parts of the selected date
            _currentSelectedDate: {
                day: 0,
                month: 0,
                year: 0
            },

            //Returns the currently selected date in its three
            //constituent parts
            getSelectedDateRaw: function () {
                return this._currentSelectedDate;
            },

            //Returns the currently selected date as a moment
            getSelectedDateAsMoment: function () {
                var _selectedDate = this._currentSelectedDate,
                    _fromArray = [
                        _selectedDate.year,
                        _selectedDate.month,
                        _selectedDate.day
                    ];

                //If all constituent parts of the selectedDate
                //are 0, return the moment of the current date/time
                if (_.reduce(_fromArray,
                    function (num, memo) {
                        return num + memo;
                    }, 0) === 0) {

                    return moment();
                }

                //return the selectedDate as a moment
                return moment(_fromArray);
            },

            //Returns the currently selected date in all three formats--
            //raw, as a moment, and as a native Date--as a convenience
            getSelectedDate: function () {
                return {
                    selectedDate: this.getSelectedDateRaw(),
                    selectedDateAsMoment: this.getSelectedDateAsMoment(),
                    selectedDateAsDate: this.getSelectedDateAsMoment().toDate()
                };
            },

            //Break a dateObject into its constituent parts
            setSelectedDate: function (dateObject) {
                var _moment = dateObject || moment(), //Assume dateObject is a moment
                    _selectedDate = this._currentSelectedDate;

                //If the date object is not a moment, make it one
                if (!moment.isMoment(dateObject)) {
                    _moment = moment(dateObject);
                }

                //Throw if the dateObject is not a valid moment
                if (!_moment.isValid(_moment)) {
                    throw 'DatepickerMediator: Invalid selected date.';
                }

                _selectedDate.day = _moment.date();
                _selectedDate.month = _moment.month();
                _selectedDate.year = _moment.year();
            },

            //Set the selected month: @month can be a string or a number
            setSelectedMonth: function (month) {
                //We must test this way since a month of 0 is valid, which is falsey.
                var _hasMonthParam = !_.isUndefined(month) && !_.isNull(month) && month !== "";

                this._currentSelectedDate.month = _hasMonthParam
                    ? moment().month(month).month()
                    : moment().month();
            },

            //Set the selected year
            setSelectedYear: function (year) {
                this._currentSelectedDate.year = year
                    ? moment().year(year).year()
                    : moment().year();
            },

            //Set the selected month: @month can be a string or a number
            setSelectedDay: function (day) {
                this._currentSelectedDate.day = day;
            },

            //Publish the selected date with all constituent parts
            publishViewReady: function () {
                postal.publish({
                    channel: _self.activateWith.internalMessageChannel,
                    topic: messagetopics.view_ready + this.state,
                    data: this.getSelectedDate()
                });
            },

            states: {
                'uninitialized': {},
                'initialized': {
                    _onEnter: function () {
                        this.setSelectedDate(_self.content.queryable());
                    },                        
                },
                'month': {
                    _onEnter: function () {
                        _self.currentView(this.state);
                        if (this.priorState !== k.initialized) {
                            _self.publishZoom(k.in);
                        }
                        this.publishViewReady();
                    },
                    '/view/change/months': function (newMoment) {
                        var s = newMoment.selection;
                        //When transitioning to the months state, we need
                        //to set both the month and the year since both are
                        //relevant in the months state
                        this.setSelectedMonth(s.month());
                        this.setSelectedYear(s.year());
                        this.transition(k.months);
                    },
                    '/view/change/years': function (newMoment) {
                        this.setSelectedYear(newMoment.selection.year());
                        this.transition(k.years);
                    }
                },
                'months': {
                    _onEnter: function () {
                        _self.currentView(this.state);
                        _self.publishZoom(this.priorState === k.years ? k.in : k.out);
                        this.publishViewReady();
                    },
                    '/view/change/month': function (newMoment) {
                        var s = newMoment.selection;
                        this.setSelectedMonth(s.month());
                        this.setSelectedYear(s.year());
                        this.transition(k.month);
                    },
                    '/view/change/years': function (newMoment) {
                        this.setSelectedYear(newMoment.selection.year());
                        this.transition(k.years);
                    }
                },
                'years': {
                    _onEnter: function () {
                        _self.currentView(this.state);
                        _self.publishZoom(k.out);
                        this.publishViewReady();
                    },
                    '/view/change/months': function (newMoment) {
                        this.setSelectedYear(newMoment.selection.year());
                        this.transition(k.months);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    /**
     * @publishes animation_zoom
     * An *animation zoom* message is used to tell a subscriber to perform a zoom animation (i.e. scale down or scale up).         * 
     */
    /**
     * @method publishZoom
     * Publishes a message over the internal message channel telling the incoming view to zoom.
     * @param {String} direction Direction of the zoom animation, *in* or *out*.
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.publishZoom = function (direction) {
        postal.publish({
            channel: this.activateWith.internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.animation_zoom,
            data: {
                direction: direction
            }
        });
    };

    /**
     * @publishes popover_resize
     * A *popover resize* message is used to tell a containing popover to resize itself based on changes in the popover's content.
     */
    /**
     * @method publishResizePopover
     * Publishes a message over the outlet message channel telling the containing popover to resize.
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.publishResizePopover = function () {
        postal.publish({
            channel: this.content.outletMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.popover_resize
        });
    };

    /**
     * @publishes popover_close
     * A *popover close* message is used to tell a containing to close based on a request from popover's content.
     */
    /**
     * @method publishClosePopover
     * Publishes a message over the oulet message channel telling the containing popover to close.
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.publishClosePopover = function () {
        postal.publish({
            channel: this.content.outletMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.popover_close
        });
    };

    //TODO: Create an activation contract
    /**
     * @method activate
     * Durandal lifecycle handler.  Read the Durandal documentation on `activate` and activation data [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html#composition-lifecycle-callbacks).
     * @param {Object} activationData Data to pass into this viewModel upon activation.
     * @durandal
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.activate = function (activationData) {
        this.subscribeAll();

        //Import content
        this.content.queryable              = activationData.queryable;
        this.content.outletMessageChannel   = activationData.outletMessageChannel;

        //Set the keyboard context for all layouts
        this.activateWith.keyboardContext   = activationData.keyboardContext;

        //Transition to the initial state (FSM)
        this.stateMachine.transition(k.initialized);
    };

    /**
     * @method compositionComplete
     * Durandal lifecycle handler.  Read the Durandal documentation on `compositionComplete` [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html#composition-lifecycle-callbacks).
     * @param {HTMLElement} [view] The view (HTML) that corresponds to this viewModel.
     * @param {HTMLElement} [parent] The view (HTML) that corresponds to the parent view of this child view.
     * @durandal
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.compositionComplete = function () {
        //We start out in the standard month view
        this.stateMachine.transition(k.month);
    };

    /**
     * @method detached
     * Durandal lifecycle handler.  Read the Durandal documentation on `detached` [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html#composition-lifecycle-callbacks).
     * @param {HTMLElement} [view] The view (HTML) that corresponds to this viewModel.         
     * @durandal
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.detached = function () {
        utils.unregisterSubscriptions(this.subscriptions);
        this.stateMachine.removeAllBusIntegration();

        this.currentView = null;
        this.stateMachine = null;
    };

    /**
     * @method subscribeAll
     * Register subscriptions with the message bus.
     */
    DatepickerMediator.prototype.subscribeAll = function () {

        var _mediator = this,
            _internalMessageChannel = this.activateWith.internalMessageChannel,
            _subscriptions = this.subscriptions;

        /**
         * @subscribes datepicker_executed
         * Subscription responding to a date actually executed by the user.  This date is published to the `DatepickerWidget` itself to insert into the input field.
         */
        _subscriptions.push(postal.subscribe({
            channel: _internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.datepicker_executed,
            callback: function (data) {
                /**
                 * @publishes widget_result
                 * A *widget result* message carries the payload of whatever the user selected.
                 */
                postal.publish({
                    channel: _mediator.content.outletMessageChannel,
                    topic: messagetopics.widget_result,
                    data: data.currentItem.asMoment.toString()
                });
            }
        }));

        /**
         * @subscribes datepicker_dateSelected
         * Subscription responding to a date selected by the user.  Selection is not the same as execution.  A user *selects* a date simply by navigating 
         * with the keyboard.
         */
        _subscriptions.push(postal.subscribe({
            channel: _internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.datepicker_dateSelected,
            callback: function (data) {
                _mediator.stateMachine.setSelectedDay(data);
            }
        }));
        /**
         * @subscribes datepicker_monthSelected
         * Subscription responding to a month selected by the user.  Selection is not the same as execution.  A user *selects* a month simply by navigating 
         * with the keyboard.
         */
        _subscriptions.push(postal.subscribe({
            channel: _internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.datepicker_monthSelected,
            callback: function (data) {
                _mediator.stateMachine.setSelectedMonth(data);
            }
        }));
        /**
         * @subscribes datepicker_yearSelected
         * Subscription responding to a year selected by the user.  Selection is not the same as execution.  A user *selects* a year simply by navigating 
         * with the keyboard.
         */
        _subscriptions.push(postal.subscribe({
            channel: _internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.datepicker_yearSelected,
            callback: function (data) {
                _mediator.stateMachine.setSelectedYear(data);
            }
        }));
        /**
         * @subscribes popover_resize
         * Subscription responding to a request from the current view in the `DatepickerWidget` to resize the popover.  This request is then republished 
         * up to the `DatepickerWidget`.
         */
        _subscriptions.push(postal.subscribe({
            channel: _internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.popover_resize,
            callback: function () {
                _mediator.publishResizePopover();
            }
        }));
        /**
         * @subscribes popover_close
         * Subscription responding to a request from the current view in the `DatepickerWidget` to close the popover.  This request is then republished 
         * up to the `DatepickerWidget`.
         */
        _subscriptions.push(postal.subscribe({
            channel: _internalMessageChannel,
            topic: messagetopics.popover_close,
            callback: function () {
                _mediator.publishClosePopover();
            }
        }));
    };

    return DatepickerMediator;
}
```

);

**datepickerMediator.html**

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="visible: currentView() === 'month'">
        <div data-bind="compose: {
            model: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonth', 
            view: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonth', 
            activate: true, 
            activationData: activateWith }"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: currentView() === 'months'">
        <div data-bind="compose: {
            model: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonths',
            view: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonths',
            activate: true,
            activationData: activateWith }"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: currentView() === 'years'">
        <div data-bind="compose: {
            model: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerYears',
            view: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerYears',
            activate: true,
            activationData: activateWith }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [compositionComplete](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html) for Durandal.